# How use Android Action Bar Style Generator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Sorry by question but i search and not found this thing so easy to much =/, i Download my action bar theme from http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ and put the files in correct place, but not happening when i execute my app, the action bar is the default i put this in styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/Theme.Barraacao</item>
</style>
```

The name of my theme is Barraacao, i make the theme whit AppCompat how my android app, please someone have a suggestion ?

Comment: Try removing the `<item>` and changing the `parent` to be `Theme.Barraacao`.

Comment: Did you update the theme in your manifest xml?

Comment: No, how i update please ?

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat has more themes that .Light, so try @CommonsWare comment or put directly your Theme in your manifest:

`<application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.Barraacao">`

It was ok for me.

Look: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html